# Plotting 2 vectors against each other

Tags: r

I'm obviously missing something obvious here; this simple code generates an error - can someone point out my mistake?!

```
times <- c(0:365)
t1 <- seq(0,365)

plot(times,t1,lty="l")

> source(.trPaths[5])
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : 
  invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8
```

removing the `lty="l"` plots the graph in the default way, with each point shown.

Comment: Your plot command specifies a line type of "l". The error message says you specified an invalid line type. Have you tried investigating `?plot` and `?par` for how to plot lines with valid line type specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plot call is wrong. You want to call `plot(times, t1, type="l")`.
See also `?plot` and `?par`.

Comment: Thanks for this - misreading help files is what happens when you work too late on a friday evening...!